# How many bytes of memory is a tweet?

Tags: string, memory

140 characters.  How much memory would it take up ?

I'm trying to calculate how many tweets my EC2 Large instance  Mongo DB can hold.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Twitter [uses UTF-8 encoded messages](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/counting_characters).

[UTF-8 code points can be up to <s>six</s> four octets long](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), making the *maximum* message size **140 x 4 = 560 8-bit bytes**.

This is, of course, just for the raw messages, excluding storage overhead, indexing and other storage-related padding.

e: Twitter successfully let me post the message:

> ™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™™

Yes, that's 140 trademark symbols, which are [three octets each in UTF-8](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2122/index.htm)

Comment: UTF-8 encodes code points, not glyphs. Each code point can be up to 4 octets in UTF-8, UTF-16, and UTF-32. CESU-8 encoding can use 6 octets for a single code point, but that only comes from naive encoding of UTF-16 into UTF-8, and is not actually valid UTF-8.

Comment: Terminology and math updated, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Worth pointing out that every tweet isn't 140 characters, and that as Twitter's user base becomes more international (or doesn't), bigger code points will be used more (or less) frequently.

Comment: While that's true, the question asks about the size in the context of determining storage requirements, so thinking about the maximum size instead of the average size is more correct.

Answer (score 4):

Back in September, an engineer at Twitter [gave a presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TdY0jU697lY#at=27) that suggested it's about 200 bytes per tweet.

Of course you still have to account for overhead for your own metadata and the database itself, but 200 bytes/record is probably a good place to start.

Comment: Twitter [uses UTF-8 encoded Unicode](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/counting_characters) -- 140 characters will *not* mean 140 bytes unless you're restricting all possible messages to the lower 127 ASCII range.

Comment: @Charles: http://www.mail-archive.com/twitter-development-talk@googlegroups.com/msg06972.html says it's just a byte count. Have things changed since then?

Comment: [their current API docs](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/counting_characters) say that they count code points, but doesn't set an upper boundary on byte size.  Judging from some of the confusion in that mailing list thread, I expect that the API doc is newer than the discussion there.

Answer (score 0):

Typically it's two bytes per character if you're storing Unicode as UTF-8, so that would mean 280 bytes max per tweet.

Comment: UTF-8 characters *can* be more than two octets in size.  For example the [trademark glyph](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2122/index.htm) is three octets long.  Wikipedia suggests the maximum possible size is six (!!!) octets.

Answer (score 0):

Probably 284 bytes in memory ( 4 byte length prefix + length*2). Inside the DB I cannot say but probably 280 if the DB is UTF-8, you could add some bytes of overhead, for metadata etc.

Answer (score 0):

Potentially of interest:
http://mehack.com/map-of-a-twitter-status-object
Anatomy of a Twitter Status Object

Also more about twitter character encoding:
http://dev.twitter.com/pages/counting_characters

Comment: currently -> https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/counting-characters

Answer (score 0):

It's technically stored as UTF-8, and in reality, the slide deck from a tweeter guy here http://www.slideshare.net/raffikrikorian/twitter-by-the-numbers gives the real stat about it:

> 140 characters, ~200 bytes